# Translation of "bowl"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, vocabulario

I have heard many different translations for bowl (the dish) in different Spanish-speaking countries. What words are normally used to translate "bowl"? Which is most universally understood? What regional variants are there?

Comment: What kind of bowl?

Comment: A bowl of soup or a mixing bowl? The two most obvious examples.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the top of my head, I use here in Spain, quite interchangeably:

- [**bol**](https://dle.rae.es/bol): a generic hemispheric vessel (any size).
- [**ponchera**](https://dle.rae.es/ponchera): a large bowl (e.g. a punch-bowl)
- [**cuenco**](https://dle.rae.es/cuenco): also generic, but smaller ones
- [**tazón**](https://dle.rae.es/taz%C3%B3n): the below kind of bowl (with a "foot"):

[image]

Comment: +1 `bol` and `cuenco` are news to me :)

Comment: *Ponchera* is another possible translation.

Comment: `bol` is the most familiar to me

Comment: @leonbloy where are you from / what dialect of Spanish do you speak/know?

Comment: @theforestecologist Argentina (Buenos Aires)

Comment: I learned _cuenco_ as "water-shed": vivo en el cuenco del lago Llanquihue. However, a quick Google shows that this must just be an extensión.

Comment: @Conrado I think that would be ["cuenca"](https://dle.rae.es/cuenca). Though maybe somewhere "cuenco" is used for that meaning, who knows...

Comment: @MikMik sorry, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: ponchera is punch bowl.

Comment: falta: palangana y fuente: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-spanish/bowl

Answer (score 7):

I think that "at least when I grew up" we called bowls by their function.

- "Plato de sopa" (soup plate)
- "Plato de cereal" (cereal plate)
- "Plato hondo" (deep plate)

Comment: please try to spell words correctly both in English and Spanish

Comment: Believe me I tray

Comment: @Fortunato: I tray?  *sigh*

Comment: plato de sopa is a bowl  full of soup. plato sopera is soup bowl.

Answer (score 5):

I learn confusing vocabulary best visually, so I want to try to clarify this a bit using pictures.

**Cuenco o Bol:**

[image] [image]

[*Bol* more often used for larger bowls]

**Tazón:**

[image] [has a "foot"]

**Plato hondo:**

[image] [literally "deep plate"]

The above seem to be the most distinct uses of these various words that I have picked up on. However, it seems many people/dialects use each of these words more broadly (or synonymously) or even not at all.

- As pointed out in [another answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1368/16908), some dialects seem to just use *Plato* with certain context words to refer to bowls.

<sup>(Note: I am a native English speaker trying to relearn Spanish, so if you disagree, have further input, better pictures, etc., please update or comment. Thanks!)</sup>

Comment: Native speakers, please feel free to agree or disagree with my generalizations as you see fit. But please mention your dialect and what you use instead (if not already stated in another answer).

Comment: plato hondo is not a bowl. It's a soup or pasta dish. But your answer is the best so far.

Answer (score 3):

I am Cuban for me the correct answer is `Plato Hondo` (deep plate).

Comment: That's a good option, actually, the best. But somebody has already answer that. So, if you agree, you should upvote that answer, but not add a new answer repeating information.

Comment: @c.p. The OP asked about regional differences. The other answer doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: plato hondo is a soup **dish** or plate.

Answer (score 3):

Bowl is translated as **pana** in my country. I'm from Nicaragua

Quoting from [the Diccionary of Americanisms](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pana)

> **pana**
>   V.    1.  f. Gu, Ho, **Ni**. Vasija circular de metal o plástico para usos domésticos.

Comment: Hola, Betsy, bienvenida a Spanish Exchange. Si te fijas, he editado bastante tu post. Procura incluir alguna referencia a diccionarios u otros textos donde se respalden o puedan corroborarse tus afirmaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Soy de Mexico y mi familia y yo le decimos al "bowl" plato hondo.